# Reading height of average graphic tablet

Tags: drawing-tablet

I got an UGEE graphic tablet. This is first graphic tablet for me as a beginner. Its reading height is only 3mm between surface and tip of pen.

Did I measure reading height correctly?

Do basic graphic tablets have tiny reading height?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the tablet and manufacturer. For example my Wacom Intuous Pro has a reading height of 12-14 mm with quick a measurement, more than that if you use the airbrush pen. This is 4 times as much as your tablets value. Although I seem to remember that the old Wacoms had a even higher height, but my memory might be off. You should probably be able to ask this value form the manufacturers before you purchase.